# How can a string be assigned to a const char*?

Tags: c++

How is it possible to assign a string (an array of chars, if I'm understanding this correctly) to a `const char*`? Any other pointer requires the `new` keyword followed by a type, but in this case the string is just assigned to a pointer. The pointer is a memory address, not an array of chars, but somehow it accepts the array of chars as a value.

(I really have tried finding an answer to this, but as I'm beginner I might have missed it, apologies if that's the case.)

Comment: Do you mean string literals?

Comment: A `const char*` can be assigned just like any other non-`const` variable since the variable itself is not `const` - only what it's pointing at. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/nbaa14jnr)

Comment: A literal string (like `"foo"`) is really an array of null-terminated constant array of characters. When you use a pointer variable (like `const  char* bar = "foo";`) then you make the variable point to the first element (fist character) of the array. You can make a pointer point to anything it's allowed to point. For example you could have `int a; int* p = &a;` and have the pointer `p` point to the variable `a`. No `new` or dynamic allocation needed.

Comment: `const char*s = "Test";` does _not_ assign a _string_ to a `const char*`.  The _string literal_ is first converted to the type and address of its first element,   That address is assigned to `s`.

Comment: Or when using strings, lets say we have `char s[] = "foo";` then you could do `char* bar = s;` and it works similar to when using literal strings, except that the string can be modified.

Comment: question requires more context to be properly answered or marked as duplicate.

Comment: If you ask for the `char *` C style string, please change the tag to `C`.  If you mean `std::string`, please explicitly ask for it. You get completely different answers for both cases.

Comment: A short sample piece of code demonstrating assigning a string to a `const char*` could help clear up the confusion over what you mean by "string". Your understanding is close (but not quite) to what a C-style string is, but given your confusion, you might be referring specifically to a string literal. In either case, you would not be talking about a `std::string` which is what many C++ programmers mean by "string". Describing your context in words is good -- better than using code alone -- but using words plus code can be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays can be implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

Most (but not all) operations on arrays perform this conversion, so arrays and pointers are often confused with each other. Good job figuring out the difference early on.

---

> Any other pointer requires the `new` keyword

Not true, consider this:

```
int x;
int *y = &x;
```

While you should know what they do, the manual use of `new` and `delete` is discouraged in modern C++, unless you're writing your own container or smart pointer.

Comment: Hmm. String literals are a funny kind of array. While `const char* a = "abc";` is OK, `const char* b = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};` will not compile.

Comment: @AdrianMole In your example, the string literal works like any other array would. The difference is caused by the brace-enclosed list not being an array (and having no type to begin with).

Comment: @AdrianMole It's the same between strings and other stuff, e.g. [here](https://godbolt.org/z/PoErvPda1). You can initialize an array with an initializer list, you can initialize a pointer with an array, but you can't initialize a pointer with an initializer list.

Comment: @NathanPierson But there is no direct equivalent of the string literal for other array types, unless there's something in a new C++ Standard that I haven't caught up with yet.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you're saying there.